# SwiftUI: Have background thread wait for UI update

Tags: swiftui, concurrency

I have SwiftUI app with a background thread running a simulation.  At certain points in the simulation I want to display the current state in the UI.

I can notify the system that the UI needs updating by changing an @Published property.  However, I really need the simulation to then pause until the UI update is complete.  That way it will display the current results as opposed to the state of the simulation sometime later when the UI gets around to updating.

I assume this must be possible, but I haven't found it in the somewhat complex concurrency model for SwiftUI.

Thanks

Comment: An `AsyncStream` could be what you need but there is no way to help since you haven't provided any relevant code to describe your setup

Comment: I believe the problem with something like AsyncStream is that I would have to copy the simulation's data into an object which is returned by it.  The simulation is somewhat complex and for efficiency I'd like to not have to copy the current state into another structure.  I really would like to pause the background simulation until I know the UI has been updated to show the current state.  I haven't shown specific code because I've tried an number of schemes, but none work.  I was hoping a description of the issue would suffice for someone to give me a pointer.

Comment: You don't need to copy everything; just the minimal data that the UI needs. That said, you could certainly look at AsyncChannel (https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md), which offers back-pressure, so that when `send` is called, it won't progress until the data is accepted. But there's no lifecycle notice when "the UI completes." That can be arbitrarily far into the future (and can even be indefinitely into the future) due to animations. You need to make a stable copy of what the UI needs.

Comment: Why would you have to copy the state? AsyncStream is likely the best and simplest solution with the right setup. All you do is continue the state, “variables in structures” will likely not pass Swift 6 checks and wouldn’t be very concurrent In the new sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the entire intent of having a `@Published` property. This property must only be updated on the UI thread (the main queue, the main actor, etc). When the update is to happen, the engine should write to the `@Published` property, which will cause the UI to update on the same thread, blocking until it completes. As long as you update the UI entirely based on the `@Published` property, your system will remain consistent.

Comment: I don't think that is true.  Modifying the @Publish property just schedules an update of the UI.  It doesn't happen synchronously.  If my background thread continues to run then when the UI is updated, it uses later values of the simulation. To be clear, I update the property from the background thread using:                        DispatchQueue.main.async 
                        {
                            modelData.updater.toggle()
                        }

Comment: I take it that `updater` is the `@Published` value here? And that it is a Bool? Then the only data you may rely on in the UI is that Bool. I suspect that you're actually using other values that are the `@Published` property (or perhaps that your publishing an object that you modify on other threads, which is not permitted). You must bundle all of the data the UI needs into a single object (ideally a value type), and assign that to the `@Published` property.

Comment: Yes, updater is Published.  It is only used to trigger an update of the UI.  Nothing else that could change during the simulation is Published.  The problem I'm having is that by the time the UI is updated as the result of changing "updater", the simulation has advanced and I don't show the correct values.  If there were an event such as .onUpdated I could attach to the view in order to know when it was updated, I could stop the simulation and restart it in .onUpdated.  Unfortunately, I don't see anything like that.

Comment: There's nothing like that. Everything that the UI relies on should only ever be modified on the main thread, and should be atomic to that. For what you're describing, you absolutely should copy the UI-driving values (which is not your whole state; it's just the final things the UI needs to react to) and Publish them or send them on a stream/channel. "Pause until the SwiftUI renderer promises it will never read this data again until signaled" is not a thing, and likely would never be a thing. It's not how the system is designed to work.

Comment: Understood.  I've realized I will need to copy the display data anyway because I ultimately want to be able to display the results in a time graph.  I will need a snapshot of the data at each time interval.  So I will just bite the bullet and copy what is needed.  Thanks for your help.